# problems with echo img tag

Tags: php

I'm having problems echoing the src and alt attribute in the img tag. It doesn't display the image at all. Does any one know how I should be structuring this?

```
echo '<td rowspan="7">' . <img src=$row[url] alt=$row[caption] height="250" width="300"/> . '</td>';
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quoting is all messed up:

To fix your method with single-quoting and concatenation, use:

```
echo '<td rowspan="7"><img src="' . $row['url'] . '" alt="' . $row['caption'] . '" height="250" width="300"/></td>';
```

Or all as a double-quoted string, enclosing the variables in `{}` and placing single quotes around all attributes:

```
echo "<td rowspan='7'><img src='{$row[url]}' alt='{$row['caption']}' height='250' width='300'/></td>";
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to enclose the `<img>` tag in the quotes (and don't forget the double quotes around attribute values):

```
echo '<td rowspan="7"><img src="' . $row['url'] . '" alt="' . $row['caption'] . '" height="250" width="300"/></td>';
```

Also, rather than concatenating the string, you can use commas to `echo`. It's a trivial performance boost (users will almost certainly never notice), but good to know nonetheless!

```
echo '<td rowspan="7"><img src="', $row['url'], '" alt="', $row['caption'], '" height="250" width="300"/></td>';
```

Don't forget to sanitize your `$row` data so a stray `"` doesn't break your site.

Answer (score 2):

Your `img` HTML still needs to be in a string if you're trying to concatenate it:

```
echo '<td rowspan="7">' . "<img src=$row[url] alt=$row[caption] height=\"250\" width=\"300\"/>" . '</td>';
```

or simpler:

```
echo "<td rowspan=\"7\"><img src=$row[url] alt=$row[caption] height=\"250\" width=\"300\"/></td>";
```

Comment: Thanks Amber, it works! But why does it need to be in a string for? I don't know why i'm concatenating it, its something I read online. Is it best not to?

Comment: If it isn't in quotes PHP will think that it is PHP, not HTML and error out. As for concatenating, it shouldn't be. At least not between the `td` and `img` tags. Also, I would suggest surrounding your variable in curly brackets `{}`. I'm surprised that it even works without them, as it is an array element called using a key `$array['something']`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are after this should work:

```
echo '<td rowspan="7"><img src="{$row[url]}" alt="{$row[caption]}" height="250" width="300"/></td>';
```

Comment: thanks for your comment above. Does it matter when or where I use `"` and `'` because I don't know which is the right way or does it not matter? e.g some posts stated `"<td rowspan='7'>"` and another `'<td rowspan="7">'`

Comment: I usually go for the double quotes on the outside. The reason for this is that you can call variables directly inside double quotes and they will be interpreted. So if I do something like `$str = 'test'; echo "test: $str";` the output will be `test: test`. If I had used single quotes on the outside it would not have interpreted. So `$str = 'test'; echo 'test: $str';` would output `test: $str` which is less than ideal. That said, if you are really into efficiency, it is more efficient to use single quotes if you are not outputting a variable. So there are a couple schools of thought. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to separate the html tags from your php code, like this:

```
<td rowspan="7"><img src="<?php echo $row[url] ?>" alt="<?php echo $row[caption] ?>" height="250" width="300"/></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<td rowspan="7"><img src=".$row[url].'" alt='".$row[caption].'" height="250" width="300"/></td>';
```